# How to add a domain user account to Windows Enterprise 8.1?

Tags: user-accounts, windows-domain, microsoft-account

I have a computer on a domain and login with a Microsoft Account.  Now, I would like to add a true domain account (domain\user) to the users allowed to login to this computer.  Numerous examples can be found to login to a domain using a Microsoft Account, but none to add a domain account!

How do I do this?

Comment: You add the user just like you did in Windows 7 and any previous version of Windows. There is an option to create a non-Microsoft local user in Windows 8. **With a domain user you do that on the domain server anyways.**  Talk with your IT admin for more information.

Comment: You add domain users to the domain, not the computers.

Answer (score 2):

By default, *all* domain users can log onto (almost) any machine connected to an Active Directory domain.  You do not need to add any user specifically to allow them access.